# Bluez-Can we connect to HSP/HFP service using 2 Bluetooth headset's with signficantly less time to switch audio

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I am working on Bluez-5.30 stack to pair and connect with multiple BT audio devices (HFP and HSP devices).

Can we connect have switching between 2 2 bluetooth headsets simultaneously.

The requirement is to play the audio on both HFP and HSP devices pair and connected with my Linux laptop with significantly less time to switch.

Comment: Yes, It is possible to achieve audio connection switching between 2 headsets (SCO connection) with significantly less time interval of 1 or 2 seconds.
I have worked on BlueZ 4.0 and PulseAudio 6.0 to achieve this on Ubuntu 15.04 Linux laptop.
 
Problems found:
1.      Bluez4.0 restricts service level connection to only 1 headset after pairing.
2.      Pulseaudio6.0 takes 4 seconds time duration to switch the SCO connection from one headset to another.

Comment: Solutions:
1.      BlueZ4.0 which has the support of HSP & HFP profiles, restricts to have service level connection with only 1 headset.
Modified it have 2 service level connections at the same time.
2.      Then it is found that while switching audio from one headset to another, there is a significant delay of 4 seconds observed with noise.
This has been debugged by compiling Pulseaudio 6.0, and found that SCO connection with previous headset gets released after 4 seconds timer duration from the time it moves to idle state.
Reduced the time duration to 500ms